# Is there any difference between "mutex" and "atomic operation"?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system

I'm learning Operating System now, and I'm quite confused with the two concepts - **mutex** and **atomic operation**. In my understanding, they are the same, but my OS instructor gave us such a question,

> Suppose a multi-processor operating system kernel tracks the number of processes created by each user. This operating system kernel maintains a counter variable for each user that it increments every time it creates a new process for a user and decrements every time a process from that user terminates. Furthermore, this operating system runs on a processor that provides atomic fetch-and-increment and fetch-and-decrement instructions.
>   Should the operating system update the counter using the atomic increment and decrement instructions, or should it update the counter in a critical section protected by a mutex?

This question indicates that mutex and atomic operation are two things. Could anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 30):

An [**atomic**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearizability) operation is one that cannot be subdivided into smaller parts. As such, it will never be halfway done, so you can guarantee that it will always be observed in a consistent state. For example, modern hardware implements atomic compare-and-swap operations.

A **mutex** (short for [**mutual exclusion**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion)) excludes other processes or threads from executing the same section of code (the [**critical section**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section)). Basically, it ensures that at most one thread is executing a given section of code. A mutex is also called a [**lock**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)).

Underneath the hood, locks must be implemented using hardware somehow, and the implementation must make use of the atomicity guarantees of the underlying hardware.

Most nontrivial operations cannot be made atomic, so you must either use a lock to block other threads from operating while the critical section executes, or else you must carefully design a [**lock-free algorithm**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm) that ensures that all the critical state-changing operations can be safely implemented using atomic operations.

This is a very deep subject, and there is a large body of literature on all these topics. The Wikipedia links I've given are a good starting point, but since you're taking a class on operating systems right now, it might be best for you to ask your professor to provide good resources for learning and understanding this stuff.

Comment: NO. A mutex, by itself, cannot «exclude other processes or threads from executing the same section of code».
Mutexes help programmers to prevent something from happening, but in no way a mutex can exclude anything (by itself).
If we delete a file, we can exclude other processes or threads from reading it. 
But without deleting it and by only creating a second file, with the same name and an extension «please_do_not_touch_me» (which is what, more or less, what a mutex does),
we exclude «almost...» nobody from reading it.

Comment: @iliasiliadis: I think you're being overly pedantic here. A mutex excludes other processes or threads _which are running the same code as the current process and thread_ from executing the same section of code (the critical section). Yes, it's true, _unrelated_ processes and threads are free to interact with the same external resources as my critical section -- but they aren't _running_ my critical section, which is the important distinction.

Comment: And of course there is also the distinction between a single-process (userland) mutex and a cross-process (kernel) mutex; I didn't want to get into that level of technical detail in this answer, which is a high-level summary rather than an in-depth explanation.

Answer (score 10):

If you're a total noob, my answer may be a good place to start.  I've just learned how these work, and feel I'm in a good place to relay back.

Generally, both of these are means of avoiding bad things that happen when you read something that's halfway written.

---

**Mutex**

A mutex is like the key to a bathroom at a small business.  Only one person ever has the key, so if some other person comes along they'll likely have to wait.   Here's the rubs:

- If someone walks off with the key, then the waiting person never stops waiting.
- Nothing can stop some other process from making its own door to the bathroom.

In the context of code, a mutex is mostly the key part, and the person is a process.

---

**Atomic**

Atomic means something that can't be split into smaller steps.  In the natural world there is no CPU clock -- so everything we do could be smaller steps -- but let's pretend...

When you're typing on your keyboard, every key you hit is an atomic action.  It happens all at once, and you can not hit two keys at exactly the same time.  Here's what's good about this:

- No waiting: the fact that no two keys are being hit at the same time is not because one has to wait.  It's because one is always done by the time the next gets there.
- No collision: no matter how much you hammer away, you'll never get two characters overlaid.  One always happens before the other, completely.

For a counter example, if you were trying to type two words at the same time, that would be *not atomic*.  The letters would mix up.

In the context of code, hitting keys is the same as running a single CPU command.  It doesn't matter what other commands are in queue, the one your are doing will finish in its entirety before the next happens.

If you can do something atomically, then you don't have to worry about collision.  But not everything is feasible within these bounds.  Generally, atomics are for really low level operations -- like getting and setting an primitive (int, boolean, etc).  For anything that's going to run a bunch of CPU commands but wants to be atomic, there's a couple tricks:

1. Use a mutex.  Kind of cheating, not really atomic.  But some things do this and call themselves atomic.
2. Carefully writing code such that it never requires more than one concurrent instruction on a piece of data in a row to remain correct.  This one gets a bit deeper, but sometimes it can be done.

---

From here there's tons of reading to get into the nitty gritty details, but this should be enough to give you a foundation understanding of the subject.

Answer (score 4):

first read @Daniel answer then mine.

If your processor provides atomic instructions enough to complete your task you do not need Mutex/locks. In your case `fetch-increment` and `fetch-decrement` are supposed to be atomic so you do not need to use Mutex.

Atomic operations use low level/hardware level locks to make some operations ATOMIC: operations which are virtually performed in one go/cpu cycle. So atomic operations never place system in inconsistent state

**EDIT**

No Atomic and Mutex are not same thing but two *opposite* things used for same purpose of making sure that state of system should not become inconsistent. You use Mutex for Non-ATOMIC operations while for ATOMIC operations you do not use Mutex.

Comment: Daniel says *"Underneath the hood, locks must be implemented using hardware somehow, and the implementation must make use of the atomicity guarantees of the underlying hardware."*, but you say *"Atomic operations use low level/hardware level locks to make some operations ATOMIC"*.